# SystemVerilog Variable index in generate block items

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I write SPI slave BFM module with several SPI interfaces. I use Active-HDL 9.1. I generate several blocks(spi slaves) in my SystemVerilog code. I also write functions in which I read and reset data in this blocks. This is a part of my code:

```
module bfm_spi(itf_spi);
   parameter C_NUM = 1;
   parameter C_DATA_WIDTH = 32;

   spi_interface  itf_spi [C_NUM];


   genvar i;
   generate
      for(i=0; i < C_NUM; i++) begin : bfm_spi_arr
     bfm_spi_1 #(.C_DATA_WIDTH(C_DATA_WIDTH)) bfm_spi_1_i (itf_spi[i]); 
      end
   endgenerate

   /**
    * Reset all input buffers
    * */
   task Reset;
      integer i;
      for(i = 0; i < C_NUM; i++) bfm_spi_arr[i].bfm_spi_1_i.Reset(); //Error this
   endtask // Reset
```

During a compile compiler write error for line, in which I note "Error this".

> Error message: Generate block item selection with variable index is
>   not supported: i

If I replace i with constant number, complile is OK.

```
module bfm_spi(itf_spi);
   parameter C_NUM = 1;
   parameter C_DATA_WIDTH = 32;

   spi_interface  itf_spi [C_NUM];


   genvar i;
   generate
      for(i=0; i < C_NUM; i++) begin : bfm_spi_arr
     bfm_spi_1 #(.C_DATA_WIDTH(C_DATA_WIDTH)) bfm_spi_1_i (itf_spi[i]); 
      end
   endgenerate

   /**
    * Reset all input buffers
    * */
   task Reset;
      integer i;
      for(i = 0; i < C_NUM; i++) bfm_spi_arr[0].bfm_spi_1_i.Reset(); //OK
   endtask // Reset
```

How I can select several bfm_spi_1_i block in generate in my task Reset()? This BFM module is used only for simulation, not for implemantions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do create an interface or abstract class with an implementation that calls each Reset() inside the generate

```
interface class Reset_c; // you can use a virtual class if your simulator does not yet support interface classes.
  pure virtual task Reset;
endclass
Reset_c R_h[C_NUM]; // array of handles to each implementation instance
 for(genvar i=0; i < C_NUM; i++) begin : bfm_spi_arr
   bfm_spi_1 #(.C_DATA_WIDTH(C_DATA_WIDTH)) bfm_spi_1_i (itf_spi[i]); 

   class Reset_imp implements Reset_c;
     virtual task Reset;
        bfm_spi_1_i.Reset()
     endtask
  endclass
  initial R_h[i] = Reset_imp::new;
 end : bfm_spi_arr

   task Reset;
      for(int i = 0; i < C_NUM; i++) R_h[i].Reset();
   endtask // Reset
```